# How can I disable extension compatibility checking in Firefox 7 beta?

Tags: firefox, compatibility, firefox-extensions

Does anyone know what to add to the `about:config` to stop Firefox 7 beta checking extension compatibility?

I've tried all the settings I can find online for previous versions and I can't get anything to work (changing them where applicable when they contain the version number in the setting).

Answer (score 1):

Oh, dangit. Asked too soon. I forgot about the [**Add-on Compatibility Checker**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-on-compatibility-reporter/) add-on. Installed that and it lets you enable potentially incompatible add-ons.

Well, maybe my forgetfulness will help someone else looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

And for those who like to live on the edge, go to `about:config` and modify the `extensions.checkCompatibility` setting.